# Django shell interprets characters differently in different situations

Tags: python, django, shell, encoding

I have a python script named load.py that creates some Django models
ie it runs commands like:

```
User.objects.create(pk=1, name=u"Jake")
```

I am trying to run this script in the django shell using:

```
python manage.py shell < load.py
```

The problem is when I have special characters.  For example the following line

```
User.objects.create(pk=1, name=u"“Jake”")
```

Works totally fine when I copy and paste it manually into the shell.
However when I run

```
python manage.py shell < load.py
```

I get the following error:

Warning: Incorrect string value: '\xC2\x80\xC2\x9CPa...' for column 'name' at row 1

Any idea why this might be happening?  Thanks

Comment: Probably has to do with the encoding of your text editor.

Comment: @mattm any suggestions on how to solve it?  I am not really using a text editor its just the terminal

Comment: Where are you editing `load.py`?

Comment: @mattm I wrote the file in sublime and then uploaded it to my server through CyberDuck.  I see that you can change the encoding of a file in vim, but what encoding should I use to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the encoding in my SQL database.  Changing the columns encodings to utf-8 solved the problem.